# Unmount without sudo

Tags: mount, sudo, root, fstab, non-root-user

I know that I can declare in `/etc/fstab` that a user can mount and unmount a partition without root permission using `user(s)`. But I seem to be unable to achieve the same in a `mount` command without fstab entry.

#### Attempts

I tried the following options: `user`, `users`, `owner`, `group` (the last two with and without specifying a value). But the issue is that, since it is not an fstab entry, I have to use `sudo` anyways, and the manual (for `users`) says:

> Allow any user to mount and to unmount the filesystem, even when some other **ordinary user** mounted it.

Which seems to imply that if the root user mounted it, it does not matter, which I confirmed through my experiments

#### Question

Is there any way to mount (with root permissions) in a way that allows ordinary users to unmount, without an fstab entry?

Comment: sudo with access to single command (unmount) is no-go?

Comment: the point is to allow a plain `umount`, which, contrary to `mount`, does not seem to pose any security threats